# Why is non-greedy Python Regex not non-greedy enough?

Tags: python, regex, non-greedy

I've implemented non-greedy regex on a group of string URLs, where I'm trying to clean them up so that they end after the .com (.co.uk etc).  Some of them continued with `'` or `"` or `<` after the desired cutoff, and so I used `x = re.findall('([A-Za-z0-9]+@\S+.co\S*?)[\'"<]', finalSoup2)`.

The problem is that some URLs are misc@misc.misc'misc''misc' (or similar with < >) and so after implementing the non-greedy regex I'm still left with `enquiries@smart-traffic.com.au">enquiries@smart-traffic.com.au`, for example.

I've tried two `??`'s together, but obviously not working, so what's they proper way to acheive clean URLs in this situation?

Comment: or maybe just made the \S+ non-greedy : [A-Za-z0-9]+@\S+?.co\S*?)[\'"<]

Comment: Question is not clear to me. Can you please give some details. Examples will do.

Comment: On a side note, parsing HTML with regex is **not the best idea**, especially since you're already using BeatifulSoup.

If you need, say, to get all `a`s that have `href`s and extract those `href`s, BS allows you to do exactly that in a couple lines, without any regex tomfoolery.

Comment: I'm in the processes right now of learning the correct usages of different techniques.  Your comment is actually very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your regex is that you currently are only looking for Non-spaces(period)co instead of looking for Non-spaces(period)Non-spaces.

So in this case you could get away with the following regex based on the information above.

```
>>> finalSoup2 = """
... misc@misc.misc'misc''misc
... enquiries@smart-traffic.com.au">enquiries@smart-traffic.com.au
... google.com
... google.co.uk"'<>Stuff
... """
>>>x = re.findall('([A-Za-z0-9]+@[^\'"<>]+)[\'"<]', finalSoup2)
>>>x
['misc@misc.misc',
 'enquiries@smart-traffic.com.au',
 'enquiries@smart-traffic.com.au\ngoogle.com\ngoogle.co.uk']
```

Which you can then use to get the urls that you'd like but you'd have to make sure to split them on `r'\n'` as they may have a newline character within the text as seen above.